# Como copiar arquivos preservando seus metadados?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um script que identifica os arquivos alterados em duas pastas e depois copia (caso alterados na data de modificação) de um para outra, sincronização.

Para copiar os arquivos já tentei usar:

```
shutil.copy() 
shutil.copy2() 
shutil.copystat()
```

Eles copiam os arquivos, mas não copiam a **data/hora de modificação** o que faz que os mesmos arquivos sempre apareçam quando rodo o script.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

[`shutil.copy2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) é perfeitamente capaz de copiar os metadados contendo a data e a hora da ultima modificação do arquivo:

> shutil.**copy2**( *src, dst,* * *, follow_symlinks=True* )
>
> Identical to `copy()` except that `copy2()` also attempts to preserve all
>   file metadata.
>
> `copy2()` uses `copystat()` to copy the file metadata. Please see
>   `copystat()` for more information about platform support for modifying
>   symbolic link metadata.

Segue um código capaz de garantir que a origem será copiada para o destino juntamente com todos os metadados possíveis. Se o destino possuir uma data de criação mais antiga que a origem, o destino sera sobreescrito com a origem:

```
import shutil
import os

def sincronizar( src, dst ):

    # Verifica se origem existe
    if not os.path.exists( src ):
        return -1; # Erro

    # Copia se o arquivo de destino
    # nao existir
    if not os.path.exists( dst ):
        shutil.copy2( src, dst )
        return 1; # Sucesso

    # Recupera metadados da origem e do destino
    dst_info = os.stat(dst)
    src_info = os.stat(src)

    # Copia somente se a data de modificao do arquivo
    # de destino estiver mais antiga que 1 segundo
    if( src_info.st_mtime - dst_info.st_mtime > 1 ):
        shutil.copy2( src, dst )
        return 1 # Sucesso

    return 0 # Sucesso (sem copia)
```